# SQL Number of rows

Tags: mysql, count, rows

I am trying to pull the total number of rows in a SQL table.

I am using the following code:

```
$rowNum = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logs");
$count = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowNum);
echo "Rows: " . $count;
```

However, the output I get is `Rows: Array` rather than something like `Rows: 10`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) returns an associative array with the result column names as keys and the result values as values. If you run `var_dump($rowNum)`, you'll see an array with `COUNT(*)` as key and the number as value. You can use `$rowNum["COUNT(*)"]` or, better, alias the count expression and use the alias to refer to the value.

```
$rowNum = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM Logs");
$count = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowNum);
echo "Rows: " . $count["total"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_fetch_assoc` function fetches an associative array that represents one result row.

Try this:

```
$rowNum = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS log_count FROM Logs");
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowNum);
$count = $rows["log_count"];
echo "Rows: " . $count;
```

See the documentiation for [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) on php.net for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

Comment: Retrieving all the rows with all the values from the whole table just to count how many there are is extremely inefficient.

Comment: why not just use select count(*)?  You are pulling a lot of unneeded data just for a row count

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL development project has made its source code available under the terms of the GNU General Public License, as well as under a variety of proprietary agreements. MySQL is also used in many high-profile, large-scale World Wide Web products, including Wikipedia, Google (though not for searches), Facebook, and Twitter. You can refer here to know more about  [MySQL Table](https://web.archive.org/web/20170415035600/http://learnwebdevelopment.info/2011/08/how-to-get-last-row-from-database-table/) which generates the web page document.